# How to import working directory for JUnit from maven to IDEA

Tags: import, junit, intellij-idea, working-directory, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to make new developers of my maven project to have as easy start as possible. I am using and recommending IntelliJ IDEA as an IDE for them. I am pretty satisfied with the results of importing the maven project to IDEA. The only complication that I have now is importing of the working directory from the surefire plugin.

In my pom.xml I have the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>target/work</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works fine when i run the tests from command line (mvn test).
When I create new Idea project, the JUnit tests need aditional setup however. The working directory is ignored and I have to manually set it up to be able to run the tests properly.

Do you have any idea how to make Idea import the working directory for JUnit properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check a discussion in [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-52286). [There an easy workaround](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-52112) for this problem:

set **working directory** to `$MODULE_DIR$` in the **defaults** for the run configuration that you will use.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the $MODULE_DIR$ variable in the Idea run settings. The working directory is set to the directory, where the project is located. I needed to set the working directory to $MODULE_DIR$\target\work to have it properly set. This is a little bit better, because now i can use this constant string and let others just copy+paste it. It still needs manual intervention tho.

Comment: So there's no way to inherit the working directory from maven ?