# Maven and Intellij builds differently

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I have a parent pom.
When I am on the parent and write `mvn clean install` my dropwizard application builds fine.

However, in Intellij it fails because it cannot find my `config.yml` file.

The problem is that I need to include my module directory in Intellij, but not in Maven. Why is that?

Running `mvn install` this works

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new CivilizationApplication().run(new String[]{"server", "src/main/resources/config.yml"});
}
```

In Intellij I must change to the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new CivilizationApplication().run(new String[]{"server", "civilization-rest/src/main/resources/config.yml"});
}
```

How can I configure Intellij, so it will work without specifying the module directory?

Comment: What are you using in maven to execute this code?

Comment: Both `mvn clean install` and `mvn exec:java`. mvn clean install runs the integration tests which runs the same code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting your working directory in your run configuration...

[image]

I would also look into your `pom.xml` configuration to see if you can change the working source sets to use this directory upon importing the maven project.

Comment: What do I have to add in my pom.xml to get working source set?

Comment: The working directory totally worked! Thanks. If you could elaborate on the pom.xml then that would be great

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397860/how-to-import-working-directory-for-junit-from-maven-to-idea workingDirectory in maven didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Set `Working directory` to `$MODULE_DIR$`. Maven always uses $MODULE_DIR$, but you probably do not have $MODULE_DIR$ by default for IntelliJ Application executions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just tell Intellij to do exactly the same thing Maven does when you start it.

You can do so by clicking on the drop down menu next to the "Launch App" button. There you can define a new Run configuration that uses Maven by clicking on the + to the left and then choosing Maven.

Then you can just enter `clean install exec:java` where it says "Command line" and it should work exactly like it does when you execute it manually from the command line. Debugging should work like this as well without any problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I still would like to know why this doesn't work though... There must be some other configuration I can do

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are refering to a resource file by using a relative path instead of using the classpath.

So, instead of

```
new CivilizationApplication().run(new String[]{"server", "src/main/resources/config.yml"});
```

You better have this

```
new CivilizationApplication().run("server", getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.yml"));
```

(obviously, make sure to change the signature of the #run() method as well)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but maybe it's to do with the Resource not being copied.

I'm on OSX so the exact terms may differ if you're on Windows but for me... in Preferences, select "Build, Execution, Deployment", then "Compiler", and try adding ";?*.yml" to the Resource patterns.